# python reading file infinite loop

Tags: python, readfile

```
pronunciation_file = open('dictionary.txt')
pronunciation = {}
line = pronunciation_file.readline()
while line != '':
    n_line = line.strip().split(' ' , 1)
    pronunciation[n_line[0]] = n_line[1].strip()
    line = pronunciation_file.readline()
print(pronunciation)
```

the code is to turn a file of words and its pronunciation into a dictionary (keys are words and value is pronunciation) for example 'A AH0\n...' into {'A':'AH0'...}
the problem is if I put the print inside the loop, it prints normal(but it prints all the unfinished dictionaries) however if i put the print outside the loop like the one above, the shell returns nothing and when i close it ,it prompts the program is still running(where is probably a infinite loop)

Help please

I also tried cutting out first few hundred words and run  the program, it works for very short files but it starts returning nothing at a certain length:|

Comment: If you put the `print` inside the loop, it doesn't run infinitely?

Comment: Try putting `print(line)` in the loop to see what it thinks `line` contains and why it's not equal to `''`

Comment: @Barmar at least when it's inside the loop it prints while its outside, it doesn't print anything,,, btw is there any better way to end the loop? i only know this one from the textbook:|

Comment: Two answers have been posted that explain how to end the loop.

Answer (score 7):

That is not how to read from a file:

```
# with will also close your file
with open(your_file) as f:
    # iterate over file object
    for line in f:
         # unpack key/value for your dict and use rstrip
         k, v = line.rstrip().split(' ' , 1)
         pronunciation[k] = v
```

You simply open the file and iterate over the file object. Use `.rstrip()` if you want to remove from the end of string, there is also no need to call strip twice on the same line.

You can also simplify your code to just using `dict` and a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html)

```
with open("dictionary.txt") as f:
    pronunciation = dict(line.rstrip().split(" ",1) for line in f)
```

Comment: sry i kind of omitted the first few lines

Comment: @NestroAbarca, does not matter. A while loop is not how to read a file

Answer (score 2):

Not tested, but if you want to use a while loop, the idiom is more like this:

```
pronunciation={}
with open(fn) as f:
    while True:
        line=f.readline()
        if not line:
            break
        l, r=line.split(' ', 1)    
        pronunciation[l]=r.strip()
```

But the more modern Python idiom for reading a file line-by-line is to use a for loop as Padraic Cunningham's answer uses. A while loop is more commonly used to read a binary file fixed chunk by fixed chunk in Python.